# change theme of the responsive website on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have four type of CSS files so that I can open my website in desktop, mobile and tablet. I have called that CSS pages through javascript function in an external javascript page and called script tag in index page. 
the code I have written is below but the problem is not that as it works fine. now using this same concept I want to change the theme color of the website which opens in all i.e. mobile, tablet, desktop or any wide screen. So my Real problem is that. Please suggest me with some ideas.

the code is here which I used in .js file for responsive site for calling all css

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 350) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/mobile.css");
        } else if ((width >= 351) && (width < 600)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 601) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    }else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

now for changing theme color i have to write more css for all css. I am totally new to designing a responsive website, any help will be appreciated and all suggestions will be accepted.

Comment: i suggest you to use `media queries`. Its a single css file which has nested css for different resolutions and devices.

Comment: Yeah why aren't you using media queries?

Comment: the code which I have pasted is working fine my site is responsive site. All is good but now when i want to add feature like changing theme colour just by clicking the color button for that I have to write four css page for all systems which will open my website and for all colours. I dont know how to do that with the same functionality I have used above. this is what I really want

Comment: media queries is not working in Internet Explorer for me atleast. Please suggest me code if its working for you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If building a responsive web site, I would go for a [fluid layout together with media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). There should be no need for different css files for different widths then, unless the design changes drastically between the different widths. (Which I think it shouldn't do, since that would probably just confuse users.)

In order to change the site's color theme on a button click, I would do something similar to what you are doing now with your css files for different widths.

I would extract everything that has to do with colors into its own css file, and name it for example default-theme.css. If I then would like to switch to a dark theme by clicking on a button, I would create a new css file called  for example dark-theme.css, and register something like the following function to the button's onclick-event:

```
function adjustTheme(width) {
    $("#theme-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/dark-theme.css");
}
```

Comment: And if you want the browser to remember the chosen theme between visits, the link in liyakat's answer looks promising, unless you have something against cookies.

Comment: yep I accept this answer your answer is right but I have already tried but its not working for me. Is there any other alternatives you can tell me since you have understood my problem

Comment: ok I use media queries can you tell me how it may work for Internet Explorer, because its not working in my case but its working with chrome and firefox

Comment: You can try [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) if you want your media queries to work in IE8 and earlier. (As far as I know, they should already work in IE9 and later.)

Comment: thanks@ meliasson for sending respond.js. this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use only single css file. As it would be difficult to maintain everything in separate css files. You can use css media query for the same: [Css3 Media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
<!-- purple-theme.css is the default theme. I have maintained 3 more css files, red-theme.css, blue-theme.css and green-theme.css in the same css location -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="purple-theme.css" class="change-theme" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click', ".btn-color-change", function() {
        $(".change-theme").attr("href", this.id + "-theme.css");
    });
    </script>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <button id="red" class="btn-color-change">Red theme</button>
        <button id="green" class="btn-color-change">Green theme</button>
        <button id="blue" class="btn-color-change">Blue theme</button>
        <button id="purple" class="btn-color-change">Purple theme</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 color-theme" style="border:5px solid white">
            Keep looking up… that’s the secret of life. - Charlie Brown</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 color-theme" style="border:5px solid white">
        The first step is you have to say that you can. - Will Smith
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about a dark theme or light team for your website, you can do it automatically with CSS only and if you want a toggle, you can do it manually too.

## Automatically change theme

For this, you can use the `prefers-color-scheme`, setting it to `dark` or `light`. Example code:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
        --color-secondary: #339eff;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #ffffff;
        --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
    }
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test
  </body>
</html>
```

## Manually toggling theme

You can manually toggle it too, using created classes, in example, `.dark-mode` or `.light-mode`. Example code:

```js
document.getElementById("theme").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]');
  if (meta.content === "light") {
    meta.content = "dark";
    document.body.classList.remove("light-mode");
    document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
  } else {
    meta.content = "light";
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    document.body.classList.add("light-mode");
  }
});
```

```css
.light-mode {
    --color-primary: #ffffff;
    --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
}

.dark-mode {
    --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
    --color-secondary: #339eff;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test

    <button id="theme">Change theme</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Finally, manual and automatic, together

Just combine them, for you to have an simple solution to your question. Example code:

```js
document.getElementById("theme").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="color-scheme"]');
  if (meta.content === "light") {
    meta.content = "dark";
    document.body.classList.remove("light-mode");
    document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
  } else {
    meta.content = "light";
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    document.body.classList.add("light-mode");
  }
});
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
        --color-secondary: #339eff;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    :root {
        --color-primary: #ffffff;
        --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
    }
}

.light-mode {
    --color-primary: #ffffff;
    --color-secondary: #ff7e33;
}

.dark-mode {
    --color-primary: #0a0a0a;
    --color-secondary: #339eff;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test

    <button id="theme">Change theme</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Just a quick reminder...

The meta tags used on the header each have a purpose.

```
    <!-- This tells the browser your website supports both dark and light theme, preferring the dark version-->
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
    <!-- This tells the browser to look the preferred styles on the media query-->
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
```