# Load different CSS files on button click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to allow the user to change the 'theme' of the website when he clicks on theme 1 it loads a different CSS file then when the user clicks on theme 2. How is this possible?

This is what I have tierd to do with so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var fontButton = document.getElementById('changeFont');

        fontButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/France2014/css/test.css">');
        });
    }
</script>
```

This loads the file when I click on the button, but it removes everything else inside the website and just leaves the HTML tag and CSS file, I know this because I launch the development tool inside of Google chrome.

What can I do? Is there a better way to implement this feature?I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314797/change-theme-of-the-responsive-website-on-button-click

Comment: i think you should change the `href` value just of stylesheet on every button click .

Comment: avoid using document.write()! it rewrites everything on your page with whatever you put in the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing a theme is usually done by loading in another class with JQuery.
For example:

HTML:

```
<body id='skin' class="skin-blue">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#skin').addClass('skin-red').removeClass('skin-blue');
```

To change a font-size easily, consider something like this for example:

```
var size = 20;
    function setFontSize(s) {
        size = s;
        $('#sidebar-menu').css('font-size', '' + size + 'px');
        $('#content').css('font-size', '' + size + 'px');
    }
    function increaseFontSize() {
        setFontSize(size + 5);
    }
    function decreaseFontSize() {
        if(size > 5)
            setFontSize(size - 5);
    }

    $('#inc').click(increaseFontSize);
    $('#dec').click(decreaseFontSize);
    setFontSize(size);
```

and for example a + and - button

```
 <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus" id="inc"></i>
     </a>
   </li>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
   <li>
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus" id="dec"></i>
     </a>
   </li>
</li>
```

Comment: Interesting, bascily what i want to do i just change the font size for certain divs.

Comment: This is what i wanted. Thank you for yyour time kind sir! works perfectly.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should have to change just  the `href` value of stylesheet on every button click .Doing that ,will load the new `CSS` file without affecting the DOM elements . Hope I am clear to you .

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to add id or class onclick to `<body>` tag, You will have two sets of styles:

```
.menu{
color:black}
```

and after click you will add `<body id="greenTheme">`

```
#greenTheme .menu{
color:green}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following link as a quick working example...

[enter link description here](http://www.omnimint.com/A6/JavaScript/Change-external-CSS-stylesheet-file-with-JavaScript.html)

You can see it in action here...

[enter link description here](http://www.omnimint.com/examples/Changing-external-CSS-file-with-JavaScript.html#)

Even though your attempted solution is pure JavaScript and you might not actually need it I feel the need to mention jQuery.
It should help you write less code that should be cross browser friendly too, it actually makes writing JavaScript less painful

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div before the link tag and use getElementById.innerHTML and change the contents to your desired css